# Не запускается эмулятор в проекте с JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-jetpack-compose

Не запускается эмулятор в проекте с JetPack Compose. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Заранее благодарю!

Выдает следующую ошибку:

04/30 19:06:23: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 API 28.
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_28 has terminated.

Смена виртуальных девайсов не помогает, создание новых тоже.

Содержимое MainActivity:

```
package com.example.jetpackcompose

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material.Text

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Text(text = "Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Содержимое build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Содержимое build.gradle (Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetpackcompose"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.30'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
//    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
//    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
//    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
//    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
//    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    // Material Design
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    // Material design icons
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    // Integration with activities
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03'
    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02'
    // Integration with observables
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$compose_version"

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: Т.е. если убрать JetPack Compose - то всё работает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Все это происходило в Android Studio Canary, мне и в голову не пришло проверить обычный Android Studio, до Вашего комментария. Благодарю за наводку! Действительно, дело было в эмуляторе, а не в проекте с JetPack Compose. Исправил положение переустановив в Tools -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator и Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer).

Comment: На Маке подобное наблюдалось после обновления ОС на 11.3. С приходом обновления эмулятора 30.5.6 исправлено. Ни с Котлином, ни с JetPack Compose проблема не связана.